# Old anime OVA isekai, bubble priestess, and destined protector

Tags: story-identification, anime, isekai

I remember this old anime I ordered off of Netflix in the 2000s. It was about a dying land and their priestess lineage was "dying" or something was wrong, so they had to throw their holy daughter into a fire pit. It doesn't work and she doesn't die; she is transported to modern Japan in a bubble.

She appears before a young boy and they grow up together, despite their strange meeting. Once she comes "of age," she and her protector childhood friend are whisked back into her home dimension. They meet a red haired warrior lady and are surrounded by either ghouls or zombies at a red/corrupted fountain.

*Blurry memories below*

I remember a subplot with a bandaged and abused lady, her assassin lover, and her authority figure abuser. The assassin did bad things in order to gain the authority figure's trust to steal her away, but I think they are caught and killed under the moonlight anyway.

Can't remember anything else, except the music was nice and the red haired warrior lady surrounded by crimson maple leaves in the ending song.

Answer (score 12):

I strongly believe you watched ***[Himiko-den](https://myanimelist.net/anime/360/Himiko-den)***.

From MyAnimeList:

> In a world where the dead walk, where good and evil exist as palpable forces, a darkness is stirring. The undead march against the cities of light, to capture the sacred fire that is the source of their power. But one hope remains. Called into this world by the magical flame, a young girl named Himiko is thrust into the maelstrom of danger, betrayal, and war. For she is heir to the sacred fire, and holds a power that could save its Guardians... if she survives!

It's been ages since I watched any of this, but the descriptions you gave match up well with the images I pulled out of the first episode.

The daughter is passed into the fire...

[image: Daughter in the fire]

... and sent into modern day japan (via a bubble), where she is found by a young boy.

[image: Boy finds transported young girl]

The boy and girl grow up, and then she is magically transported back to the land of her birth, and her protector follows (by heroically throwing himself into the bubble that's taking her back).

[image: Boy joining girl in bubble]

There are two warriors of the 6 female guardians waiting on the far side...

[image: 6 female guardians]

... that have red hair, and one is in a storm of red maple leaves
(however, the images are from the opening, not the ending):

[image: From the opening]

[image: from the opening]

[image: from the opening]

Enjoy!